# Why not log-transform all variables that are not of main interest?

Tags: regression, data-transformation

Books and discussions often state that when facing problems (of which there are a few) with a predictor, log-transformimg it is a possibility. Now, I understand that this depends on distributions and normality in predictors is not an assumption of regression; but log transforming does make data more uniform, less affected by outliers and so on.

I thought about log transforming all my continuous variables which are not of main interesr, ie variables I only adjust for.

Is that wrong? Good? Useless?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Now, I understand that this depends on distributions and normality in predictors
>
> log transforming does make data more uniform

As a general claim, this is false --- but even if it were the case, why would *uniformity* be important?

Consider, for example,

i) a binary predictor taking only the values 1 and 2. Taking logs would leave it as a binary predictor taking only the values 0 and log 2. It doesn't really affect anything except the intercept and scaling of terms involving this predictor. Even the p-value of the predictor would be unchanged, as would the fitted values.

[image]

ii) consider a left-skew predictor. Now take logs. It typically becomes more left skew.

[image]

iii) uniform data becomes left skew

[image]

(it's often not always so extreme a change, though)

> less affected by outliers

As a general claim, this is false. Consider low outliers in a predictor.

[image]

> I thought about log transforming all my continuous variables which are not of main interest

To what end? If originally the relationships were linear, they would not longer be.

[image]

And if they were already curved, doing this automatically might make them worse (more curved), not better.

--

Taking logs of a predictor (whether of primary interest or not) might sometimes be suitable, but it's not always so.

Comment: Many thanks for this splendid answer. I think that many of us, at least me,  needed to see it visualized this way. But do you also agree that right-skewed data should be subject to log-transforming? More than other skews and forms?

Comment: Not generally, no. Under some very specific conditions, perhaps.

Comment: I'm also surprised to see that no one mentioned interpretability of the model.  If you log transform you dependent variable, it becomes a bit more difficult to interpret the model -- especially for laymen or those without statistical/mathematical backgrounds.  For example let's say you had a model that predicted the height of a tree in ft. given the circumference of the trunk in inches. The interpretation of the $\hat{\beta}=0.50$ being , for a one inch increase in the circumference, the mean height of the tree is increased by the log of a half of foot is more cumbersome (continued)

Comment: (con't) than being able to say, for example, for a one inch increase in the number of trunk circumference circumference, the mean height of the tree is increased by the a half of foot.  The later is easier to interpret and easier to calculate in the field without a calculator.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to perform *log transformation* (and **any** *data transformation*, for that matter) just for the sake of it. As previous answers mentioned, depending on data, some transformations would be either *invalid*, or *useless*. I highly recommend you to read the following IMHO excellent *introductory material* on **data transformation**: http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bocode/t/transint.html. Please note that code examples in this document are written in *Stata* language, but otherwise the document is *generic* enough and, thus, useful to non-Stata users as well.

Some **simple techniques and tools** for dealing with common *data-related problems*, such as *lack of normality*, *outliers* and *mixture distributions* can be found in [this article](http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/dealing-non-normal-data-strategies-and-tools) (note, that *stratification* as an approach to dealing with mixture distribution is most likely the simplest one - a more general and complex approach to this is *mixture analysis*, also known as *finite mixture models*, a description of which is beyond the scope of this answer). *Box-Cox transformation*, briefly mentioned in the two references above, is a rather important data transformation, especially for non-normal data (with some caveats). For more details on Box-Cox transformation, please see this [introductory article](http://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/normality/making-data-normal-using-box-cox-power-transformation).

Answer (score 8):

Log transforming does not ALWAYS make things better. Obviously, you can't log-transform variables that achieve zero or negative values, and even positive ones that hug zero could come out with negative outliers if log-transformed.

You should not just routinely log everything, but it is a good practice to THINK about transforming selected positive predictors (suitably, often a log but maybe something else) before fitting a model. The same goes for the response variable. Subject-matter knowledge is important too. Some theory from physics or sociology or whatever might naturally lead to certain transformations. Generally, if you see variables that are positively skewed, that's where a log (or maybe a square root or a reciprocal) might help.

Some regression texts seem to suggest that you have to look at diagnostic plots before considering any transformations, but I disagree. I think it's better to do the best job you can at making these choices before fitting any models, so that you have the best starting point possible; then look at diagnostics to see if you need to adjust from there.

Comment: All add that these considerations apply both to important and unimportant predictors.

Comment: Thanks @rvl! I' m always confused by the discordance between when and how to choose transformations; books often state that, as you wrote, one needs to check the form of all variables before touching regression. Thanks for providing your insights.

Comment: @rvl, thank you for your answer. Would you log-transform the `snoq` dataset in this [CrossValidated thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136144/mixture-of-gaussians-on-log-of-data) (bearing in mind the goal is to fit a mixture of Gaussians)?